# What does "hold down a corner" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I have come across it in this [video](https://youtu.be/-L7o6HtX8Vg). It is 13 minutes and 23 seconds.

> There are times when you get bunched up, and you might be with two or three people to **hold down** a corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't tell what it meant without seeing what the video was about; but I think it means "keep control of a particular spot".

Comment: Either that or its about three or four people trying to make a bed together in a strong norwester when the sheets get bunched up. If they each hold down a corner, and if they are anything like the big boring guy in the video, then they should get it done in at least 13 minutes.